# 3D graphics of gps data in Gnuplot

Tags: 3d, gps, gnuplot

I have 1000 XYZ datapoints (GPS latitude,
longitude, altitude), from a walk up Mount Kilimanjaro.

I would like to make a 3D plot using vertical lines thus
    (x0 y0 0)-(x0 y0 z0), 
    ...
    (x999 y999 0)-(x999 y999 z999).

GpsPrune will do this sort of plot, and animate it as well, 
( http://activityworkshop.net/software/gpsprune/index.html ) 
but I would like more control over the details.

So can this be done in gnuplot? 
And would it be possible to colour segments of each line,
where colour = f(altitude)?

```
Richard H
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great question!

Plotting a vertical line from `z=0` to a certain value is what the plotting style `impulses` does.

Selecting a variable linecolor according to the `z`-value can be done with `linecolor palette`, which uses the current palette to get the respective line color.

For testing I used the data file

```
0 0 0
0.1 0.1 1
0.2 0.2 1.1
0.5 0.5 1.2
1 0.5 2
1.5 1 2.5
1 2 4
0.8 1.8 3.5
```

The script for plotting is:

```
set ticslevel 0
set zrange[0:*]
set view 40,40
set termoption dashed
unset key

splot 'gps.dat' using 1:2:3:3 with impulses lw 2 linecolor palette, \
      '' using 1:2:3 lc rgb 'black' lt 2 lw 0.5 w l
```

which gives the output (with 4.6.4):

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I was able to generate a set of gifs (pseudo animation). The news for Kilimanjaro climmbers is that **set view 70,190,** is the best of (a very nice) bunch.

Comment: Sample image at http://users.skynet.be/watermael/Kilimanjaro.html but this is just a first hack - still working on it

Answer (score 0):

latitude and longitude have not the same scale, only at the equator.
to make a simple transform to cartesian, you can multiply each longitude with the cos(middleLatitude).

```
latNew = lat; // stays the same
lonNew = lon * cos(latAvg); // corrects the fact that longitudes shrinks the more north or south from equator the position is.
```

Otherwise yor graphic will look a bit stretched.
I would additionally convert the latNew and lonNew to meters, then your diagramm has an all 3 axes the unit meters.

degrees to meter factor = 40 000 000 / 360.0;  // earth circum fence divided by num degrees

After this trasnformation you can use any 3d plotting software.

Comment: In the Kilimanjaro walk, (Max latitude, Min Latitude) = (-2.95, -3.41) so I dont think the error is too troubling.  I have run into this problem at higher latitudes and generally use Perl's GIS::Distance module, default option Haversine. The z dimension of the figure does need a bit of stretching - walking up Kilimanjaro's 5.8 km z dimension feels a bit different than 5.8 km in the x-y plane.

Comment: yes you are for hat latitude. but perls distance does not help for higher latitudes, it calc only the distance, but you need to transform all points to cartesian